# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

I've just stumbled upon a new crash that i've encountered yet.. the crash report is as follows..

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa16df4b9
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b5126e4 __kill + 8
1   TradeMate                       0x002d7d48 0x30000 + 2784584
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3b575720 _sigtramp + 40
3   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2fba794c -[AVAudioSession privateBeginInterruption] + 48
4   Foundation                      0x315eae46 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30bd1f1c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                  0x30bd13e2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30bcfbd2 __CFRunLoopRun + 626
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30b3a46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30b3a24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
10  GraphicsServices                0x358742e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
11  UIKit                           0x333ef840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
12  TradeMate                       0x0003ed86 0x30000 + 60806
13  TradeMate                       0x00037284 0x30000 + 29316
```

It says something about `AVAudioSession`..But have no clue how to fix it..  Please can anyone help me in this.. thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` exceptions are from trying to send a message to an object that has been deallocated. 
This can happen for example if you create your `AVAudioSession` object in a local variable.

Comment: thank you for the help but i already got the answer from above.. :)